# Alternative to _timestamp in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the best way to determine the last modified time for a record in Elastic Search? I don't mind storing it as a separate field, but setting it manually would require a great deal of extra overhead. In the past, I used _timestamp, but that has been deprecated as of 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ES 2.0, you need to store that timestamp as a separate field yourself. Or if you're using Logstash to populate your ES cluster, it's even easier, since Logstash can do it for you automatically.

As of ES 5, you'll be able to leverage [ingest nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html) and define a pipeline composed of a [date processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/date-processor.html) which will add that timestamp for you, similar to what Logstash currently does.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this mutate statement in filter section. This works.

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "[fields][event_time]" => "%{timestamp}" }

}
```

This will add current timestamp into this field.